# Push notification not received, windows universal 8.1

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-notificationhub

HI i have implemented push notification in my application, serer is sending notification but not receiving at my end.

```
          void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string typeString = String.Empty;
            string notificationContent = String.Empty;
            switch (e.NotificationType)
            {
                case PushNotificationType.Badge:
                    typeString = "Badge";
                    notificationContent = e.BadgeNotification.Content.GetXml();
                    break;
                case PushNotificationType.Tile:
                    notificationContent = e.TileNotification.Content.GetXml();
                    typeString = "Tile";
                    break;
                case PushNotificationType.Toast:
                    notificationContent = e.ToastNotification.Content.GetXml();
                    typeString = "Toast";
                    // Setting the cancel property prevents the notification from being delivered. It's especially important to do this for toasts:
                    // if your application is already on the screen, there's no need to display a toast from push notifications.
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                case PushNotificationType.Raw:
                    notificationContent = e.RawNotification.Content;
                    typeString = "Raw";
                    break;
            }

            //   string text = "Received a " + typeString + " notification, containing: " + notificationContent;
            var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                // rootPage.NotifyUser(text, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

                if (typeString == "Toast")
                {
                    PushNotificationHelper.AddTostNotification(0, notificationContent);
                }
                else if (typeString == "Badge")
                {
                    PushNotificationHelper.AddBadgeNotification(0, notificationContent);
                }

            });
        }

        public async void InitChannel()
        {
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

            try
            {
                var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

                if (channel != null)
                {

                    //String existingChannel = (String)roamingSettings.Values["ExistingPushChannel"];
                    roamingSettings.Values["ExistingPushChannel"] = channel.Uri;

                    dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
                    channel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;

                }
                else
                {
                    roamingSettings.Values["ExistingPushChannel"] = "Failed to create channel";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                roamingSettings.Values["ExistingPushChannel"] = "Failed to create channel";
            }
        }

        public async void InitNotificationsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                String existingChannel = (String)roamingSettings.Values["ExistingPushChannel"];

                string tempDevelopmentKey = "";
                string Platform = "";

                List<string> arrayTags = new List<string>();

#if WINDOWS_APP
                Platform = "windows-tablet";
             tempDevelopmentKey = "dev_WindowsTabletNotification";
#endif

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            Platform = "windows-phone";
            tempDevelopmentKey ="dev_WindowsPhoneNotification";
#endif

                arrayTags.Add(Platform) ;
                arrayTags.Add(tempDevelopmentKey) ;

                string TMBNotification = (string)roamingSettings.Values["TMBNotification"];
                if(TMBNotification != null)
                {
                    if(TMBNotification == "on")
                    {
                        arrayTags.Add("TMB");
                    }
                }
                string TRSNotification = (string)roamingSettings.Values["TRSNotification"];
                if (TRSNotification != null)
                {
                    if (TRSNotification == "on")
                    {
                        arrayTags.Add("TRS");
                    }
                }
                string IMNotification = (string)roamingSettings.Values["IMNotification"];
                if (IMNotification != null)
                {
                    if (IMNotification == "on")
                    {
                        arrayTags.Add("IM");
                    }
                }
                string SWSNotification = (string)roamingSettings.Values["SWSNotification"];
                if (SWSNotification != null)
                {
                    if (SWSNotification == "on")
                    {
                        arrayTags.Add("ANC");
                    }
                }
                string VIDNotification = (string)roamingSettings.Values["VIDNotification"];
                if (VIDNotification != null)
                {
                    if (VIDNotification == "on")
                    {
                        arrayTags.Add("videos");
                    }
                }


                var hub = new NotificationHub("hubname", "endpoint");
                var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(existingChannel, arrayTags);

                // Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
                if (result.RegistrationId != null)
                {

                }

            }catch
            {

            }
        }
```

So how can i confirm that there is no issue in my implementation or there is issue from server end.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of steps you can take to debug this problem:-

- There is broadcast and sending notification, using notification hub, option available on azure portal(you can do from VS also from left side server explorer). When you did this there is a log that will show you whether a notifications sent successfully or not.
- First just delete all your registrations with notification hub and for very new registration check is your device getting registered with correct tags/channel uri or not(this you cad do from server explorer too)
- Make sure you are `sending/registering` the correct templates that are corresponding to `WNS` service.
- make sure you are using WNS service this different from what is for
  WP8 silverlight one.

  [image: ServerExplorer]

You can see the errors just at the bottom of this page if any.
There is option for device registrations from where you can alter the registrations.

- [image: DebugNotificationHUb]